# unable to redirect to some view in Django python

Tags: python, django

AoA,
   I am trying to redirect to some view, but failed to do so.

here is the code

```
views.py

def logout(request):
        c = {'username': 'Create Account', 'status': ''}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    response = render_to_response("home.html",c)
    response.delete_cookie('id')
    request.session['id'] = 'None'
    return redirect('/home/')

def home(request):
       #some code here 
       return render_to_response('blah blah')
```

urls.py

url(r'^home/$', 'contacts.views.home_Page'),
  url(r'^logout/$', 'contacts.views.logout'),

the above code redirect me to -- let's suppose current URL(127.0.0.1/account)
it redirects me to (127.0.0.1/account/home) but i want to redirect to 127.0.0.1/home
how can I redirect to specific view ?

Comment: You should use `return redirect('/home/')`, but it's really strange that without return, it redirects your to `/account/home`

Comment: What's the url conf of the logout view, and how did you call that view?

Comment: that was a typing mistake..I have change the redirect to return redirect and updated my url.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`redirect(to[, permanent=False], *args, **kwargs)` returns an HttpResponseRedirect to the appropriate URL for the arguments passed. You need to return the HttpResponseRedirect object in the view function.

BTW, you should try to avoid hardcoding urls in you code, instead you should use view names.

e.g:

urls.py:

```
url(r'^home/$', home, name='home_view')
...
```

view.py:

```
def logout(request):
    ...
    redirect('home_view')
```

Answer (score 1):

django provides a built-in [`logout`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-out) that you should use:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def log_out(request):
   logout(request)
   return redirect('home')
```

Now `'home'` can be many things; but the easiest way to make sure its pointing to the right place is to name your urls. So in your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'home/$', home, name='home')
```

Comment: ummm..then? how can I delete cookie if someone clicked on logout button :)